# how to get particepent profile info in android game using google play game services

Tags: android, google-play-games

i am developing a game in android i want to implement multilayer concept using Google play

game services

i wanted to know that how i get profile information of participant i mean name and profile

picture of player when user connected to game in android

and second question is

when i play game using random play it give the player5068 joined but i want exact name of

the

player how it possible please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to think what type of multiplayer game are you going to implement with gpgs.  Either it will be a real time multiplayer or turn based multiplayer.
In real time multiplayer you have to implement real time event listener class abstract methods. from there you can get list of participants that have joined ur room. from the participant object you can get its name , id , picture url and other properties.

Secondly you have asked about random players name , you can get it by fetching participants list in room .

Comment: You seem you know what you're talking about. Enjoy +10 rep. Maybe you could show how to implement those methods you referenced, and maybe you'll get some more.

Comment: I am currently using c++ sdk and here you can get local player as 

`gpg::PlayerManager::FetchSelfResponse localPlayer = GPGSManager::getInstance()->GetGameServices()->Players().FetchSelfBlocking( gpg::DataSource::CACHE_OR_NETWORK);`

you can explore loalPlayer and can get its name or id etc.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, please consider editing that into your answer so you can format the code for multiple lines, and it may be easier to find a working answer for someone from google in the future who has a similar problem.